# Why SerialDataReceivedEventArgs receive incomplete data?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm currently working on IO board. The serial object has been initialized and listen for incoming data. I'm reading incoming data using `SerialPort1.ReadExisting();` as the incoming string expected to arrive as **{X000000}5E** + `\r\n` in every reading.

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        TextBox2.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
        {
            TextBox2.AppendText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting());
        }));
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Couldn't open Port", "Error");
    }
}
```

When using ReadExisting() just like that, I got the result like I wanted and I will get the value of between "{X" and "}", but when I do a split char, I always got error regarding index out of bound. I change the way of reading by adding `Environment.NewLine` when reading to get whether the data is receive in a complete or not. The result will be like below image as expected.

[image]

I also try like below based from SO answer but incoming string data will be same as image above:-

```
var end = '\r';
int dataLength = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
int nbrDataRead = _serialPort.Read(data, 0, dataLength);

string RxString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
LogEvents($"Serial port data: {RxString}");
```

> It's like the full set of {X000000}5E is coming in 1-3 times in split to `SerialDataReceivedEventArgs`.

Am I reading the wrong way? I have also increase the baudrate from 9600 to 19200 but the incoming data still same as provided image. Do it has to do with the IO board program? I'm not so sure about this.

Comment: "but when I do a split char, I always got error regarding index out of bound"... there is nothing that looks like that in code samples in the post... Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, the statement is because I have 6 set of button attach to IO board. Each button represent the index of 000000. If button #2 is press, the result will be {X010000}5E. I have to substring the data and get the record from index 2, length 6 into `ToCharArray()` and find index `int i = Array.IndexOf(charData, '1');` when I'm reading at current code and substring, the will be error if the incoming data is not in complete {X######}5E.

Comment: Serial Port does not guarantee that all the send data is received in one chunk.  Windows uses timers to forward serial Port data between application and hardware interface.  The baud rate is only the transfer rate and not the actual send rate.  If device sends only 1 character a second the rate of transfer can still be 9600.  For example, suppose an application sends the time every minute and the time message contains 10 characters.  You would get 10 character a minute at a transfer rate of 9600.

Comment: @jdweng, so it depend on the device? because the programmer to the io board will be available on 2-3 days at my place. I'm just knowing the data received is depend on the device capacity based from your details.

Comment: You probably will be transferring ASCII data terminated with carriage return.  Done a  of software to interface with programmers over the years.

Comment: @jdweng I don't think windows uses timers.  The UART on the RS232 fires an interrupt and the CPU informs the OS.  The data is then read and forwarded to the application that owns the COM port.  That said, you are correct, serial port doesn't guarantee receipt of the data in one chunk.

Comment: Windows definitely uses timers.  The UART on the PC has a limited size so data must be removed quickly so the UART does not overflow.  Also events are processed using timers.  And the data is brought from the UART buffer to the application layer using timers.  Windows does not implement the UART hardware interrupt.  I've found that out in the early 80's on a 8086 PC in DOS and every version of DOS and Windows since.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @jdweng pointed out, the serial port `DataReceived` event fires somewhat randomly.  It could fire mid string and you could only receive half of the message.  You'll have to build your own string.  Most serial to serial communication use carriage returns (`\r`) or line feeds (`\n`) to determine that message is finished.  From what you told us it looks like you tack on a `<CR><LF>` at the end, so we can look for the LF to know we got the whole string.

```
char LF = (char)10;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string currentLine = string.Empty;

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string Data = serialPort1.ReadExisting();

    foreach (char c in Data)
    {
        if (c == LF)
        {
            sb.Append(c);

            CurrentLine = sb.ToString();
            sb.Clear();

            //parse CurrentLine here or print it to textbox
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
}
```

So in the example above, I'm looking for a Line Feed character to know I got the whole message. (LF or `\n`).