# Return values from serial data received to another function

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am taking serial data from a distance sensor through Arduino to Visual Studio and I have another machine that is controlled by another controller.

Return values from serial data received to another function.

My question is: how to return the values from the function?

```
public void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
```

to a while loop inside the function

```
private void btnMove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

My code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using PokeysLibSR;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Melexis
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PokeysLib pokeys;

    public Form1()
    {  
       InitializeComponent();
       serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
       serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    serialPort1.Open();
}

public void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            string line = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            string yourPortStringFormatted = Regex.Replace(line, @"\t|\n|\r", "");
            string yourPortStringFormatted1 = yourPortStringFormatted.Trim();
            double portNum = Double.Parse(yourPortStringFormatted1);
            string line1 = Convert.ToString(portNum / 100);
            this.BeginInvoke(new LineReceivedEvent(LineReceived), line1);

        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
}

private delegate void LineReceivedEvent(string line1);

private void LineReceived(string line1)
{
    textBox1.Text = line1;
}

private void btnMove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        double[] coords = new double[4] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        byte axisMask = 0;

        if (double.TryParse(tbX.Text, out coords[0])) axisMask = (byte)(axisMask + 1);
        if (double.TryParse(tbY.Text, out coords[1])) axisMask = (byte)(axisMask + 2);
        if (double.TryParse(tbZ.Text, out coords[2])) axisMask = (byte)(axisMask + 4);
        while (true)
        {
          pokeys.StartMove(false, rbAbsolut.Checked, 1, coords);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            coords[0] = -coords[0];
           pokeys.StartMove(false, rbAbsolut.Checked, 4, coords);
            coords[2] = coords[2] + 10;
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it stands, you have a never ending while loop

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `serialPort1.ReadLine();`.  I would use `serialPort1.ReadExisting();` but note you'll have to keep track of the string.  You'll probably have to build your string until you see a line feed then call your function passing that string.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59203139/2009197