# How to correctly parse received serial data into lines?

Tags: c#, .net, string, serial-port

I'm creating a program which communicates with a serial device which is constantly sending data. I'm reading data from device every 100ms (using a timer). I use `port.ReadExisting()` to receive all currently available data from the device then I try split it into lines, because I need to check some of the received data and the best way is to check lines. The problem occurs when device sends data which doesn't end with `"\r\n"` or `'\n'`.

In a perfect situation `port.ReadExisting()` returns: `"sampletext\r\nsomesampletext\nsampletext\r\n`

But a problem occurs when there's no CR or LF character at the end:

First time `port.ReadExisting()` returns this: `"text\nsamp"`

Second time `port.ReadExisting()` returns this: `letext\r\ntext\r\n"`

End result should look like this:

```
text
sampletext
text
```

But what I get looks like this:

```
text
samp
letext
text
```

My code:

This is the `timer` which runs every 100ms:

```
private void CommandTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker seriaDataWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    seriaDataWorker.DoWork += (obj, p) => PrintSerialData();
    seriaDataWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

`BackgroundWorker` which gets called by the timer:

```
private void PrintSerialData()
    {
        try
        {
            if (RandomReboot)
            {
                RebootWatch.Start();
            }
            if (COMport.IsOpen)
            {
                if (COMport.BytesToRead != 0)
                {
                    SerialPrint(COMport.ReadExisting());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException SerialException)
        {
            return;
        }
        
    }
```

Function which parses received data into lines:

```
private void SerialPrint(string data)
    {
        using (var buffer = new StringReader(data))
        {
            string line = "";


            
            while((line = buffer.ReadLine()) != null)
            {


                if (CheckForAnsw)
                {
                    ReceivedCommandData = line;
                    if (ReceivedCommandData.Contains(AnswExpected))
                    {
                        ReceivedAnsw = true;
                        ReceivedLine = ReceivedCommandData;
                        ReceivedCommandData = "";
                    }
                }

                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    AppendText(TextBox_System_Log, Color.Black, line + "\r\n");
                }
                ));
            }
        }
    }
```

I know that the problem is that `buffer.ReadLine()` treats remainder of the string which doesn't end with a  CR or LF character as a seperate line but I don't know how to fix it.

I tried using `port.ReadLine()` in the past but it is way slower and causes problems for me when serial ports get disconnected etc.

Comment: Did you tried to just append the data to the `TextBox_System_Log` instead of parsing it yourself?  If yes, what went wrong?

Comment: @Ackdari there's no problem if I simply append it to `TextBox_System_Log` but as I said this application needs to check received data and compare ir to given answers or other data so that's why I need to split it into lines.

Comment: I see this question a lot and I've answered it a lot.  There is a good write-up here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59203139/2009197

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to handle this with the `StringReader`. Instead, you can split the string yourself:

```
private static string _buffer = string.Empty;

private static void SerialPrint(string data)
{
    // Append the new data to the leftover of the previous operation
    data = _buffer + data;

    int index = data.IndexOf('\n');
    int start = 0;

    while (index != -1)
    {
        var command = data.Substring(start, index - start);
        ProcessCommand(command.TrimEnd('\r'));
        start = index + 1;
        index = data.IndexOf('\n', start);
    }

    // Store the leftover in the buffer
    if (!data.EndsWith("\n"))
    {
        _buffer = data.Substring(start);
    }
    else
    {
        _buffer = string.Empty;
    }
}

private static void ProcessCommand(string command)
{
    Console.WriteLine(command);
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try your code out and will let you know if this solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use AnonymousPipes to transport and buffer the incoming data and read them as lines to output them to somewhere.

Here is a little example which creates a server and client pipe stream, then writes data to the server in one task (with some newline in the data) and reads the data in a different task per line and outputs them to the console.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        (var writer, var reader) = CreatePipe();

        using (writer)
        using (reader)
        {
            var writerTask = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                writer.AutoFlush = true;
                writer.Write("?");
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    if (i % 10 == 9)
                    {
                        await writer.WriteAsync("!");
                        await writer.WriteAsync(Environment.NewLine);
                        await writer.WriteAsync("?");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await writer.WriteAsync((i % 10).ToString());
                    }
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                }
                writer.Close();
            });
            var readerTask = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(writerTask, readerTask);
        }
    }

    public static (StreamWriter, StreamReader) CreatePipe()
    {
        var server = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.Out);
        var client = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(server.GetClientHandleAsString());

        return
            (
            new StreamWriter(server, Encoding.UTF8),
            new StreamReader(client, Encoding.UTF8)
        );
    }
}
```

Try to adapt this code to your use case and comment if there are difficulies.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue with `\r\n` and `\n` can be covered by using `Environment.NewLine`. I'm not sure what `AppendText` does, but if you're using it to store the values, then you're overdoing it. What you need is to store all data first in a `StringBuilder` then process them, OR process each data and store them in managed type such as Array, to define each line separately. Only use the `string` in the presentation layer (if you have some GUI that you want the user to see the results).

So, what I suggest is to store the lines in `StringBuilder` Something like this :

```
private readonly StringBuilder _strDataBuilder = new StringBuilder();

private void PrintSerialData()
{
    try
    {
        if (RandomReboot)
        {
            RebootWatch.Start();
        }
        
        if(COMport.IsOpen && COMport.BytesToRead != 0)
        {
            var data = COMport.ReadExisting();
            
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data)) {   
                _strDataBuilder.Append(data);
            }   
        }
        
    }
    catch (System.IO.IOException SerialException)
    {
        return;
    }   
}

private void SerialPrint()
{
    var data = _strDataBuilder.ToString();
    
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(data)) { return; }
    
    var lines = data.Split(Environment.NewLine);
    
    if(lines.Length == 0)  { return; }
    
    
    for(int x = 0; x < lines.Length; x++)
    {
        var line = lines[x];

        if (CheckForAnsw)
        {
            ReceivedCommandData = line;
            
            if (ReceivedCommandData.Contains(AnswExpected))
            {
                ReceivedAnsw = true;
                ReceivedLine = ReceivedCommandData;
                ReceivedCommandData = "";
            }
        }

        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            AppendText(TextBox_System_Log, Color.Black, line + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        ));     
    }   
}
```

Storing them first would make things more maintainability and fixability when you want to add more processing steps or reuse the results.

Although the `SerialPrint()` is unnessary if you just re-print the data in the `GUI`. As the data already separated in lines. So, if you do

```
TextBox_System_Log.Text = _strDataBuilder.ToString();
```

Directly, would list them in lines in the default color.  However, if you intended to split them to process each line separately (to validate for instance), then it would be okay.

Comment: Doesn't this spit lines that were not fully transmitted?

Comment: @Ackdari actually I missed this part, it should be stored first, let me fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below code:

```
    public void DataReceivedSerialPort(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    readExistingData = "";
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;

    sp.ReadTimeout = 100;
    do
    {
        readExistingData = "";

        try
        {

            readExistingData = sp.ReadLine();
            if (readExistingData == "")
            {
                readExistingData = sp.ReadLine();
            }
            dataReadFromSerialPort += readExistingData;
        }
        catch
        {
            try
            {
                readExistingData = sp.ReadExisting();
                dataReadFromSerialPort += readExistingData + "\r\n";
            }
            catch { }

        }
        UI.insert_new_items_into_textBoxUARTLog(readExistingData);
    } while (readExistingData != "");
}
```